# Sumar por filas en SQL

Tags: sql

Soy un poco nuevo en SQL y tengo un marco de datos como el siguiente pero mas grande y quiero sumar algunos de los valores de la columna `attributos` por fila y guardar el resultado en una columna que ya existe llamada `Gtb`.

Trate lo siguiente pero solo me da el valor total de la columna `attributos` y no se guarda en la columna `Gtb`.

```
SELECT SUM(Attributos) AS 'Gtb' FROM Atleticos
```

Aqui les presento el marco con los resultados deseados en la columna `Gtb`

```
Nombres Attributos  Altura   Gtb    
Pedro*    0.5         5.1    0.5    
Anna      0.6         4.3       
Carla*    0.3         6.4    0.8    
Johan*    0.4         3.4    1.2    
Bryan     10           6        
Cecilia*  5           5.7    6.2
```

Comment: Lo que buscas básicamente es una suma acumulada sobre una parte de las filas. El tema es que falta algunos datos, como por ejemplo: ¿Cuál es el criterio para seleccionar las filas? (¿Qué `Nombres` tenga un asterisco al final?), También saber cuál el orden a usar es fundamental.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho bueno estoy usando un programa llamado Infowork ICM, y el programa usa un poco de SQL. La selección la estoy haciendo manual con el cursor por esto no pongo condición. Puse el asterisco para mostrar que estoy sumando los attributos de esos nombres. pero la condición la domino ahí solo pongo un `Where`  solo ando buscando el syntax para hacer una suma por nombre | ID seleccionado y entrarla en un columna que ya existe. Ya que con el `AS` solo me crea un grid.

Comment: que es ? mysql , sql server, postgres???

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer agrupando y filtrando.

Digamos, si quiero la suma de todos los atributos de pedro, no veo conveniente traer la columna atributos en la consulta, por que? porque te dara algo por este estilo en caso de que pedro este muchas veces:

```
    Nombres Attributos  Altura   Gtb    
    Pedro*    0.5         5.1    1.7    
    Pedro*    0.7         5.1    1.7  
    Pedro*    0.5         5.1    1.7
```

Como puedes ver, el motor va a traer los **n** registros que hayan de pedro y aun asi te va a llenar el campo **Gtb** con el resultado de la suma.

lo que puede hacer es, agrupar por el factor comun de tu consulta, por ejemplo:
quiere saber la suma de los atributos de x personas y la altura (ya que esta ultima no varia, suponiendo), entonces tu query puede quedar asi:

```
    SELECT NOMBRES, ALTURA, SUM(Attributos) AS Gtb FROM Atleticos
    /*y el campo por el que quiere filtrar tus resultados*/where NOMBRES in ('Pedro', 'Carla', 'Johan')
    /*agrupas*/ group by NOMBRES, ALTURA,
```

Esto te dara las suma de los atributos de Pedro, Carla y Johan.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Pero si son mas de 500 nombres diferentes como lo voy hacer?

Comment: Y esos 500 nombres de donde los traes? donde los tienes? asi te puedo guiar un poco mas

Comment: Ahora, si no necesitas filtrar por nombres espcificos puedes quitarle la clausula where

Comment: okay estoy ejecutando el codigo que me diste pero sigo teniendo el mismo resultado. no quiero el resultado total lo que ando buscando es el resultado por fila so gtb seria 0.5,1.2,1.7 usando los valores que me distes.

Comment: Pero para tener el resultado por fila debes sumar 2 campos diferentes, digamos peso_ropa + peso_casco, ya tendriamos que ver que campos quieres sumar, por que de lo contrario si quieres sumar solo de un campo ya tendrias que ver como agrupar

Comment: quiero sumar los attributos de los nombres pero no se como agruparlo de manera que sume aunque sea los primeros 25 y que no me de el total pero la suma acomulativa hasta que llegue a la total.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que el comando update para que realices la actualización de un valor de un registro que ya existe por ejemplo:

```
update atleticos set gtb = 7 where nombres='Pedro';
```

El valor 7 es el valor que deseas actualizar en el campo gtb.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, armamos un ejemplo como el tuyo:

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (
    Id          INT IDENTITY,
    Nombres     VARCHAR(255),
    Attributos  NUMERIC(15,2),
    Altura      NUMERIC(15,2),
    Gtb         NUMERIC(15,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla (Nombres, Attributos, Altura)
VALUES  ('Pedro*', 0.5, 5.1),
    ('Anna', 0.6, 4.3),
    ('Carla*', 0.3, 6.4),
    ('Johan*', 0.4, 3.4),
    ('Bryan', 10, 6),        
    ('Cecilia*', 5, 5.7)
```

Es fundamental que la tabla de entrada tenga un `ID` único para cada fila, en este caso lo simulamos con un `Id INT IDENTITY`. Lo siguiente es crear una tabla temporal dónde guardaremos el resultado de la suma acumulada, necesitamos hacer esto para luego actualizar la tabla definitva:

```
DECLARE @TablaResultados TABLE (
    Id          INT,
    Nombres     VARCHAR(255),
    Gtb         NUMERIC(15,2)
)
```

Ahora sí hacemos una consulta para lograr la suma acumulada pero solo de ciertos registros, este es un ejemplo, nota que simplemente estoy seleccionando aquellas filas dónde `Nombres` contenga un asterisco, el filtro real lo configurarás con lo que corresponda:

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  Id,
        Nombres,
        Attributos,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) RN
        FROM @Tabla
        WHERE CHARINDEX('*', Nombres) > 0
)
INSERT INTO @TablaResultados ( Id, Nombres, Gtb)
SELECT  T1.Id,
    T1.Nombres,
    SUM(T2.Attributos) AS 'Gtb'
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T2.RN <= T1.RN
    GROUP BY    
        T1.Id,
        T1.Nombres
```

Usamos una "Common table expresion" para no repetir consultas, la idea es que por cada fila haremos un `LEFT JOIN` con las mismas filas cuyo numero sean  iguales o anteriores. Aquí es fundamental establecer el Orden, si bien el acumulado final siempre es el mismo, cada parcial dependerá del orden que establezcamos mediante `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) RN`. en este caso uso el propio `ID`de cada registro original.

Si revisamos, el resultado sería algo así:

```
╔══════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ Id   ║ Nombres  ║ Gtb  ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 1,00 ║ Pedro*   ║ 0,50 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 3,00 ║ Carla*   ║ 0,80 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 4,00 ║ Johan*   ║ 1,20 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 6,00 ║ Cecilia* ║ 6,20 ║
╚══════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

Y ahora sí, usamos la temporal tipo variable `@TablaResultados` para actualizar la tabla final, solo aquellas filas que originalmente hemos filtrado

```
UPDATE  @Tabla
    SET Gtb = T2.Gtb
    FROM @Tabla T1
    INNER JOIN @TablaResultados T2
        ON T1.Id = T2.Id 

SELECT  *
    FROM @Tabla
```

El resultado final:

```
╔══════╦══════════╦════════════╦════════╦══════╗
║ Id   ║ Nombres  ║ Attributos ║ Altura ║ Gtb  ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 1,00 ║ Pedro*   ║ 0,50       ║ 5,10   ║ 0,50 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 2,00 ║ Anna     ║ 0,60       ║ 4,30   ║      ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 3,00 ║ Carla*   ║ 0,30       ║ 6,40   ║ 0,80 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 4,00 ║ Johan*   ║ 0,40       ║ 3,40   ║ 1,20 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 5,00 ║ Bryan    ║ 10,00      ║ 6,00   ║      ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 6,00 ║ Cecilia* ║ 5,00       ║ 5,70   ║ 6,20 ║
╚══════╩══════════╩════════════╩════════╩══════╝
```